# Wordpress Custom Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm building a Wordpress website and its my first time using a custom carousel. I found this idea off this codepen.

http://codepen.io/supah/pen/zZaPeE

And I was led to this repo

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

I followed the instructions and put this stylesheet in the 
in the header.php.

and this script tag before the closing body.

and npm install slick-carousel on terminal and called element in main.js, but it still doesn't work, even when I followed html structure to put the slideshow in. Am I missing anything ? I want my results to look exactly like the codepen.

```
 <div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
 </div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Slick requires JQuery](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), so make sure you have it too.

If that's not the issue, the way I use Slick is by using a class or id in the element I want to make the caroussel and then use the slick function in a script tag in the end of the page.

So if that div structure of yours had the class slick-div,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slick-div').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
    });
});
```